# OxyPlot ContextMenu for markers in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, transform, oxyplot

I'm trying to create a ContextMenu for markers of LineSeries and ScatterSeries. I'm using the OxyPlot.Wpf namespace. My current approach is to subscribe to rightclick event, and then look for the nearest point, as to find in the example provided by offical oxyplot website:

```
// Subscribe to the mouse down event on the line series
            s1.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                // only handle the left mouse button (right button can still be used to pan)
                if (e.ChangedButton == OxyMouseButton.Left)
                {
                    int indexOfNearestPoint = (int)Math.Round(e.HitTestResult.Index);
                    var nearestPoint = s1.Transform(s1.Points[indexOfNearestPoint]);

                // Check if we are near a point
                if ((nearestPoint - e.Position).Length < 10)
                {
                    // Start editing this point
                    indexOfPointToMove = indexOfNearestPoint;
                }
                else
                {
                    // otherwise create a point on the current line segment
                    int i = (int)e.HitTestResult.Index + 1;
                    s1.Points.Insert(i, s1.InverseTransform(e.Position));
                    indexOfPointToMove = i;
                }

                // Change the linestyle while editing
                s1.LineStyle = LineStyle.DashDot;

                // Remember to refresh/invalidate of the plot
                model.InvalidatePlot(false);

                // Set the event arguments to handled - no other handlers will be called.
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        };
```

Unfortunately the Series & Axis-Classes of Oxyplot.Wpf-Namespace don't offer these methods i need for transforming and checking which point is the nearest. I don't want to loop over every series' ItemsSource and calulate the ScreenPoint for every DataPoint, because there're large amounts of data in my collections (Up to 30000 in each series) and there are up to 5 series in each Plot.

This is how the XAML of my Control looks:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.Views.OxyPlotChartControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{DynamicResource WorkspaceBackgroundBrush}">
    <Grid Margin="4" Background="Transparent">
      <oxy:Plot x:Name="Plot" Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="Plot_OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
        <oxy:Plot.Axes>
          <oxy:LinearAxis x:Name="XAxis" Title="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=XAxisTitle}"
                          Position="Bottom" IsZoomEnabled="True" IsPanEnabled="True"
                          MajorGridlineStyle="Solid"/>
          <oxy:LinearAxis x:Name="YAxis" Title="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=YAxisTitle}"
                          Position="Left" IsZoomEnabled="True" IsPanEnabled="True"
                          MajorGridlineStyle="Solid"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Axes>
      </oxy:Plot>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'm doing lots of things in the code behind, because of unusual requirements, isn't nice at all, but was the best I could do:

```
namespace MyApplication.Views
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for OxyPlotChartControl.xaml
  /// </summary>
  ///   
  public partial class OxyPlotChartControl : UserControl
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the mouse button is released on the plot element.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<OxyMouseEventArgs> MouseUp;

    public OxyPlotChartControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      RegisterEvents();
    }

    private void RegisterEvents()
    {
      Loaded += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
      {
        var dpdSsc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(SeriesSourceCollectionProperty, typeof(OxyPlotChartControl));
        if (dpdSsc != null)
          dpdSsc.AddValueChanged(this, SeriesSourceCollectionChanged);
      };
    }

    internal void SeriesSourceCollectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
      ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<DataPoint>> newSources =
        SeriesSourceCollection;

      if (newSources != null && Plot != null)
      {
        if (Plot.Series == null)
          return;

        if (Plot.Series.Count == 0)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < newSources.Count; i++)
          {
            // create itemsSourceBinding
            Binding itemsSourceBinding = new Binding()
            {
              Source = this,
              Path = new PropertyPath("SeriesSourceCollection[" + i + "]"),
              Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
              UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            };

            // create colorBinding
            Binding colorBinding = new Binding()
            {
              Source = this,
              Path = new PropertyPath("SeriesColorsArray[" + i + "]"),
              Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
              UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            };

            // create line series
            LineSeries newLineSeries = new LineSeries();
            newLineSeries.Name = "Series" + i;
            newLineSeries.MarkerType = MarkerType.Square;
            newLineSeries.MarkerSize = 2.0;

            // Apply itemsSourceBinding
            newLineSeries.SetBinding(LineSeries.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding);
            // Apply colorBinding
            newLineSeries.SetBinding(LineSeries.ColorProperty, colorBinding);
            newLineSeries.SetBinding(LineSeries.MarkerStrokeProperty, colorBinding);
            Plot.Series.Add(newLineSeries);
          }
        }
        // ...  
      }     
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesSourceCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SeriesSourceCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<DataPoint>>), typeof(OxyPlotChartControl));
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<DataPoint>> SeriesSourceCollection
    {
      get
      {
        return (ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<DataPoint>>)GetValue(SeriesSourceCollectionProperty);
      }
      set
      {
        SetValue(SeriesSourceCollectionProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextMenuItemListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContextMenuItemList", typeof(List<Tuple<string, RelayCommand>>), typeof(OxyPlotChartControl));
    public List<Tuple<string, RelayCommand>> ContextMenuItemList
    {
      get
      {
        return (List<Tuple<string, RelayCommand>>)GetValue(ContextMenuItemListProperty);
      }
      set
      {
        SetValue(ContextMenuItemListProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesColorsArrayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SeriesColorsArray", typeof(Color[]), typeof(OxyPlotChartControl));
    public Color[] SeriesColorsArray
    {
      get
      {
        return (Color[])GetValue(SeriesColorsArrayProperty);
      }
      set
      {
        SetValue(SeriesColorsArrayProperty, value);
      }
    }


    private void Plot_OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      Plot.CaptureMouse();
      OxyMouseDownEventArgs newArgs = e.ToMouseDownEventArgs(this);

      if (newArgs.ChangedButton == OxyMouseButton.Right)
      {
        int indexOfNearestPoint = (int)Math.Round(newArgs.HitTestResult.Index);

        for (int i=0; i<Plot.Series.Count; i++)
        {
          // Here I want to loop over each Series and look for the nearest point,
          // and then create a context menu for the nearest point, no matter which series it is.
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Id like to know, how I get the event that a marker, or near to marker has been right-clicked, and which datapoint it is. If there's a build in support for ContextMenu would be great, but my research wasn't very successful in that direction.
But a workaround is possible if i know the point.
Any ideas? Would really help me a lot.
Thanks in advance.